# Include/Require HTTP Address

Tags: php, http, include, require

I'm in need to include a PHP file that I can only reach with a complete HTTP address. I'm confused about this topic, I've heard it's a bad practice. How can I solve that?

Comment: What does that file do? Does it serve source code? If you want alternative suggestions, you'll need to add some more details.

Comment: It's a file that's included in many of my other pages. It contains all kinds of scripts, HTML, and some analytics. I can't just put it into all those pages, because if I need to edit something minor, I'll have to go through all those pages.

Comment: in this link you see that you can do it with include Example #3 include() through HTTP http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: `include` is to load *and* interpret the contents as PHP code. Is the latter really required in this case?

Comment: @Gumbo Yes, I have some PHP in that file as well.

Answer (score 2):

from manual : http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

also read ***Security warning that attached***

If "[URL fopen wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)" are enabled in PHP (which they are in the default configuration), you can specify the file to be included using a URL (via HTTP or other supported wrapper - see List of Supported Protocols/Wrappers for a list of protocols) instead of a local pathname. If the target server interprets the target file as PHP code, variables may be passed to the included file using a URL request string as used with HTTP GET. This is not strictly speaking the same thing as including the file and having it inherit the parent file's variable scope; the script is actually being run on the remote server and the result is then being included into the local script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is not recommended to include over HTTP, unless you're really sure about the source.
If you just want to get the contents of it, without executing PHP code, you could use:

Fot this, the PHP setting allow_url_fopen must be turned on.
An other option using cURL (shamelessly taken from PHP Manual):

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

You should pass it through htmlentities() if nescessary.

If you're on the same server, you could use:

```
<?php
readfile('footer.html');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's **very** bad practice. Instead of including it, why not include a local copy of the file and use SSH to sync it with the copy on the remote server.

Comment: That would be too complicated for my needs.

Comment: Would just copying it once (or when it changes) be too complicated? Does this file change that often?