# Not able to access file from other website

Tags: php, apache, ssl, phpmyadmin

I am trying to access a php script from my other site to my new site and I Am getting this error:

> Warning: require_once(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
>   Error messages: error:14077410:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure in
>   /home/newsite/public_html/abc.php on line 3
>
> Warning: require_once(): Failed to enable crypto in
>   /home/newsite/public_html/abc.php on line 3
>
> Warning: require_once(https://www.example.com/abc/abc.xyz.php): failed
>   to open stream: operation failed in /home/newsite/public_html/abc.php
>   on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'https://www.example.com/abc/abc.xyz.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/newsite/public_html/abc.php on line 3

I just bought rapid SSL as I thought this was SSL issue and SSL is activated now but I still get same error.

Comment: You won't be able to modify the SSL settings with `require_once`. You might want to try `curl()` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549224/include-require-http-address has a bit more information on that, as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more

Comment: what does abc.xyz.php do? do you just want to output whatever that script returns?

Comment: @KasiaGogolek yes it reads from DB that I have on example.com and display it here

Comment: @aynber I am not trying to get content from there that php file executes another file that reads and calculates database and passes me response

Comment: Doing `require` or `include` on a remote URL is almost always a very bad idea. Anyone with control over the remote server can easily inject malicious code into your website because the code will be executed as PHP, the same as if it were on your local server. Also, why does the server have an invalid SSL certificate? You can get valid SSL certificates for free with letsencrypt. There's really no excuse to have invalid certificates these days.

Comment: you want to use ajax then or curl. you shouldn't require_once a non local file.

Comment: @Mike I just bought brand new SSL so I don't know why you are saying my SSL is not valid

Comment: Can you explain exactly which server has the require_once? Say Server1 is trying to access Server2 to get the data. Is the error message on Server1 or Server2? If it's on Server1, how are you trying to access the data on Server2? If the message is on Server2, you'll have to troubleshoot that particular script.

Comment: @newbie756 I apologize. I assumed the error was caused by an invalid SSL certificate. See here to try to fix that error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078182/openssl-file-get-contents-failed-to-enable-crypto

Comment: @aynber I am trying to access server 1 from server 2 this error is on server 2 as I am using php include_once('path')

Comment: Can you show your exact code, please?

Comment: @aynber <?php
    require_once('https://www.example.com/abc/abc.xyz.php');
    ?> This is code from where I am calling server 1 as abc.xyz.php returns html code

Comment: Okay. So as I said before, don't use require_once. It won't handle https properly, and you won't be able to make adjustments. Use `curl` per the first link I posted, or `file_get_contents` per the second link.